# <![CDATA[ ... ]]> not working in TYPO3 v8 Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-8.x

I recently upgraded from TYPO3 7.6 to 8.7 and discovered that using

```
<![CDATA[ { ]]>
```

to escape a curly brace in Fluid no longer works.

Any advice is appreciated?

Comment: you can also use the curly braces with a line break after the brace.

Comment: line break doesn*t work too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```xml
<f:format.raw value="{" />
```

might do the trick.

Comment: Perfect; thanks, Ryan. I actually used it like <f:format.raw value="{" /> and it works just fine.